# mogoose is obsoluting the data into database whereas after JSON.parse(JSON.stringify()) work

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I am working with NestJS for REST APIs where inside a POST request I am retrieving some nested populated data from a collection document and creating its duplicate to embed into other collection before creating. few are the observations.

1. mongoose just saves the `_id` key and obsolute all other data.
2. When I populate data with deselected `_id`, mongoose save null.
3. If I perform 2. observation and before saving `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(populated_data))` It works fine.

I don't want to `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())` for each request as it may not be an efficient way to do so(may consume CPU cycles).

Please help me out. Here's some part of the code

```
async createProjects(
    @Req() req: any,
    @Res() response: any,
    @Body() project: Project & { services: ObjectId[] },
) {
    let { services, service: _service, ...projectData } = project;
    Promise.all(
        project.services.map(async (service: string | ObjectId) => {
            const { taskGroups = [] }: any =
            (await this.servicesService.populateTaskFromService(service, {
              path: 'taskGroups',
              select: '-_id',
              populate: {
                path: 'tasks',
                select: '-_id',
                populate: {
                  path: 'form',
                  select: '-_id',
                },
              },
            })) || {};
          const _project = {
            ...projectData,
            service,
            taskGroups: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(taskGroups)),
          };
          projects.push(_project);
          return _project;
        })
    ).then((projectToCreate)=>{
        return this.projectService
        .createMany(projectsToCreate) // in service this.projectModel.insertMany(projectsToCreate) is used
        .then((createdProjects)=>res.status(200).json(createdProjects))
        .catch(...)
    }).catch(...);
}
```

Project Schema:

```
export type ProjectDocument = Project & Document;

@Schema({
  strict: false,
  timestamps: true,
})
export class Project extends BaseEntity {
  @ObjectIdColumn({ primary: true })
  _id: ObjectID;

  @Prop({ type: 'string', enum: ProjectStatus, default: ProjectStatus.DRAFT })
  status: ProjectStatus;

  @Prop({ type: Number, min: 1970, default: new Date().getFullYear() })
  year: number;

  @Prop({ type: Date, default: new Date() })
  date: Date;

  @Prop({ required: true, index: true, unique: true })
  projectNumber: number;

  @Prop({ required: true, default: new Date() })
  createdAt: Date;

  @Prop({
    required: true,
    default: null,
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: Service.name,
  })
  @Type(() => Service)
  service: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;

  @Prop({
    default: null,
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'FormsData',
  })
  @Type(() => FormsData)
  formData: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;

  @Prop({
    required: true,
    default: null,
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: User.name,
  })
  @Type(() => User)
  userId: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;

  @Prop({ type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed] })
  taskGroups: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed[];
}

export const ProjectSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Project);
```

Comment: Hey, could you provide some code for a better understanding of the issue? Such as mongoose schema and queries.

Comment: @DimiVi I have added some code of mine
here the schema says 
  `taskGroups: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed[]`

Comment: Please provide the schema and the save/create query of the entity where the data is omitted.

Comment: @DimiVi Schema and required code added

Comment: "*creating its duplicate to embed into other collection*" - why would you do that?

Comment: You can use the `.toJSON()` or `.toObject()` methods of your models, no need to `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())`

Comment: What do you mean by "*obsoluting the data*"?